# What type of API is OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Some APIs are pure specifications, while some others (like Windows API) come with their own implementation too (am I right?).

I know just about nothing of OpenGL and to begin with, I'd like to know which of the above two types of APIs is OpenGL? I mean, how can I use it in different platforms? Do I have to search the Internet and find an implementation, or is this something OpenGL already has done?

Comment: Is Google and Wikipedia broken? Though, OpenGL is a graphics API, and it's implemented by graphics card vendors. Graphics card vendors then choose to implement the rendering (etc) how ever they want to, as long as the operations does the same as the OpenGL specifications say.

Comment: ***"Is Google broken?"*** Considering the top Google search results are often to Stack Overflow questions... yes and no. It would be wonderful if Google did things like indexing the .pdf specifications on http://opengl.org/registry instead of the incomplete/inaccurate manual pages, but in lieu of that frequently quoting the specification in Stack Overflow answers helps to fix a lot of Google's inadequacies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenGL is a pure specification API

the implementation is provided by the graphics card driver, so if you want to start programming with OpenGL then first thing to do is update the drivers for your card.

the only thing not specified in OpenGL is [how to get the context for OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context) (which is required to do anything else with it)

Comment: To be fair, context creation is handled by the window system API, which is also a well-defined standard such as WGL, GLX, EGL, AGL/CGL/NSOpenGL (Apple is the worst example). Of those, GLX and EGL are the most similar (in terms of openness) to OpenGL.

Comment: Does the same go for "OpenGL ES" too?

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani yep and they are both governed by the Khronos group (as is webgl)